# How can I raise finance to build a home for my family

Tags: home-loan, home, pakistan

I live in Pakistan. I am a software engineer with 3 years of experience, I am currently living in the house which can collapse any moment with my family in it. Recently I started looking for a home for my family but wherever I go the price is between $200,000 - $400,000. My current salary is mere $800 a month. I went to the banks for loan but all of them rejected my plea because I wasn't getting up to their risk factor. I have went everywhere I could to ask for loan but got no response. I am really tensed right now because I don't know anything except building software, which in long run might provide the funding but right now I am afraid that home will either make us homeless or kill any of my family member.

I only have a $1000 saved up in my account. Please guide me, how can I muster enough money to buy a home for my family.

Comment: Have you heard of crowdfunding???

Comment: @Victor I tried going to gofundme but it doesn't support Pakistan. Other crowdfunding websites that does support Pakistan are not popular so I am afraid I won't reach the targeted amount.

Comment: Are prices in dollars or rupees?

Comment: @Brythan For ease I have converted them in US $

Comment: Is it possible to rent a place to live?

Comment: @BenMiller trust me I have spent a healthy amount of time finding a home to rent but I am unable to find one.

Comment: Do you own your current residence? Perhaps you can learn a bit about construction and make it safe to live in for now. What do people who aren't software engineers do? Is there something else you could do for money?

Comment: The lowest price, $200K is more than 20X your annual income. Much higher than 4X is a red flag. Are there rentals that you can afford?

Comment: Isn't $800/month in income significantly higher than the average? A number of sources indicate that median income is ~$1,600/year.

Comment: unfortunately i don't own the house so reconstruction is not an option, @joetaxpayer i have searched everywhere for rental but all struggles are in vain due to 1 factor or another

Comment: That does not compute. First, get rid of the submissive talk - you did not PLEAD for a loan, you applied. But seriously, it 800 USD a month is a good wage, NOONE - literlaly no one - can afford a 200k home. Something really is odd with the math here.

Comment: Hi. I am from Pakistan here. $800 is a good salary here. One can live under $500 easily. He can find a flat for around $200-$400. Buying a new house is one of the most difficult things here in Pakistan and takes a few decades to save up money for it.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, there are 2 potential solutions -

Joining with another person or 2, and buying a house with multiple bedrooms. I am in the US, and I've seen immigrants living in tight accommodations that would seem unacceptable to most of us. But, with the combined incomes, they were able to buy the house and quickly pay for it, and then buy another.

$800/mo is about $5/hr. Below US minimum wage. Use your skills to take on additional work on line. A virtual assistant position can increase your income quite a bit.

Keep in mind, as someone on the other side of the world, my advice may not be practical for you, these are just my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the laws in your country, would it be possible to buy a piece of land and build your own home using inexpensive natural materials such as  earth (cob, hand- made mud bricks, or rammed earth), rock, timber, fibre such as hemp and cement, or other materials, depending on what is easily available? You may say you have no experience in building, but neither have many other people, including women and even children, who without previous experience, have built small, solid homes to live in, at very little cost.

Together with several helpers, none of us with any previous experience, we built a two-roomed structure from cob some years back, using earth from nearby. The most expensive part was corrugated iron for the roof, which my husband installed.  Often earth-builders use earth even for the roof, and properly done, this can be very effective.  Even if you could only build one room, while planning to add others as you had the time and materials, this would be a start in living safely.

The key of course would be to be able to afford to buy a piece of land if you don't own the land on which the present unsafe structure is sitting. There is a wealth of information on the internet about how to build using any of these materials.  I feel empathy for you in your situation and would be happy to help you find information if that would assist you, if there is some way to contact you.

Answer (score 0):

You can rent out a flat. It costs around $200-$400 for a flat in Karachi, Pakistan (I am assuming the rents around other cities would be similar). You will have to pay around $1000-$2000 in advance to get the flat. While you live in that flat you can rebuild your house if it needs to be rebuild or sell it to another person. You will get enough money from it. You can save from your salary and add to the cash and buy another house in a few years.

Answer (score -1):

Wanting save enough money to purchase a home is an issue that a lot of people face, regardless of where they live. The most simple answer is to save, save, save. Create a budget so that you are able to track every dollar. After you do so for a few weeks, then you will be able to see exactly how your money is being spent and where you can cut costs. If you need to, pick up a second or third job in your spare time. Then you can contribute your salary from that to your savings. If possible, consider moving in with friends or family - paying them rent of course, but it might be cheaper than renting on your own (you might also consider exchanging house work for rent). Times might be lean when you are saving, but you should remind yourself of what the ultimate goal is.

I am unfamiliar with the government policies in Pakistan, but perhaps there is some kind of housing relief program where you can relocate to temporarily? Your situation is unfortunate and I sympathize with you. Best of luck!

Comment: thanks for the support, i am afraid just budgeting and saving won't help my scenario because giant players in the land and property business here are milking every penny out of it, leaving us employee class people no option to buy a home